# Test if converterparameter is of type System.Windows.Visibility

Tags: c#, enums

I need to check if a converter parameter is of type System.Windows.Visibility:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    //....
    if (parameter is Visibility)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("parameter is Visibility");
    }
    if (parameter is Enum)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("parameter is Enum");
    }
    if (parameter.GetType().IsEnum)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("parameter.GetType().IsEnum");
    }
    //.......
}
```

Neither of the three if conditions evaluates to true, the second and third tests being recommended approaches here in other SO questions. The debugger indicates parameter to be `System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed`, so no problem there.
Which maybe obvious fact am I overlooking?

Comment: What does putting `Console.WriteLine(parameter.GetType());` at the top of your method show?

Comment: Dang! It says it is System.String. The parameter is provided by xaml: Visibility="{Binding IsCompany, Converter={cnv:VisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Visibility.Collapsed, FallbackValue=Visibility.Collapsed}"

Comment: Looks like you want BooleanToVisibilityConverter and then don't use a converter parameter. It is a standard XAML converter. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: If BooleanToVisibilityConverter supports Collapsed I think I indeed should use that. Though I still wonder why passing a converter parameter doesn't preserve the original type.

Comment: Because XAML doesn't know the type.  It is a string.  You might be able to construct an object instances in the resources and then pass it in with StaticResource, but that is a pain.

Comment: I checked https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.convert(v=vs.110).aspx True = Visible, False = Collapsed.

Comment: @Steve Mitcham: Creating an extra resource only to make this work seems like overengineering, so I will go with BooleanToVisibilityConverter for this scenario. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71233/discussion-between-bart-and-steve-mitcham).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, text entered into ConverterParameter are considered strings, unless an object instance is brought in with a `StaticResource`